# Avoid saving commands with newlines to bash history

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

I'm trying to filter certain commands from bash history. I've read about `HISTIGNORE`, but I would like to avoid saving commands that have new lines, or commands longer than N characters.

I frequently use very long commands, and when I navigate my history with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, when the command is long enough to take all the screen space, my prompt disappears, so I would like to avoid saving these very long commands to my history.

I've tried to solve the prompt disappearing issue, but it happens in all the shells I've tried (xfce-terminal/rxvt) and with the default `$PS1/.bashrc/.profile` files that come with debian, so I suspect it is a bash related issue.

Comment: I suspect that it's really incorrect use of non-printing character designation in your `PS1` Read `man bash`. Edit your Question and show us `echo "$PS1" | od -bc`.

Comment: `bash` will not add commands to history if the 1st character on the line is a space.

Comment: Yes, I know about the space at the beginning, but I was hoping to achieve this based on length, so that I don't have to asses every command before I type it. As for the PS1, I saw other answers stating that this was an issue with the PS1 prompt, but I've tried with the default one and it didn't change anything. I also saw this behavior on other distros default shells (ubuntu for example), so I don't think is fixable.